# How to change the position of the CommandBar Overflow area in VS2015?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, commandbar

May I enquire as to how the position of the CommandBar Overflow area (when the 'see more' ellipsis button is clicked) may be changed to reside below the CommandBar (rather than above it) when the CommandBar control is positioned at the bottom of the page?

Thanks.

Comment: by overflow area you mean the overflow menu or the labels of the buttons? See the pictures of [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CommandBar);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0)&rd=true).

Comment: Hi Elvis, the overflow area includes _both_ the overflow menu [which appears as a drop-down (or rise-up) menu when the ellipsis button is clicked], _as well as_ the labels of the buttons (which are placed onto the **CommandBar** and which are not visible when the **CommandBar** is in a collapsed state). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing my code, I derived a potential way to resolve this problem as follows:

You'd need to encapsulate the XAML code for the **CommandBar** within a **RelativePanel**, then set the **CommandBar** height to the required dimension and align it with respect to the bottom of the said Panel.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying hard to figure out the logic behind that but failed... What I did to force it open on the side I want is to edit the control's template and change the visual states relevant to the wrong side to the correct ones. (Eg. replace the $State**OpenUp** code with the $State**OpenDown** if you want it to always open down.)

Comment: Hi Tamas, that's a good try - thanks for the effort in replying to my question. :)